# End of day Data aggregation?

Tags: soql, reporting

Is there a way to create an "end of day summary" of a user(s)? It would be something to the effect of a dump of all their conversation history, posts, likes etcetra. I'm using PHP as a serverside so SOQL code would probably be all I'd need, not the Java portion =)

Thanks!

Comment: @downvoter Why was this question downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, this isn't something that is going to be very easy to do within Salesforce. Are you looking to get all of their actions, such as when the login, create records, edit records, etc or are you just looking to get a history of their chatter?

To get a list of all of their actions, you are going to need several SOQL calls to call each object type with a where clause like:

```
WHERE (CreatedDate = TODAY AND CreatedBy = :userId) OR (LastModifiedDate = TODAY AND LastModifiedBy = :userId)
```

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm

You will need to run a SELECT statement on every object that you are looking to get this for. It isn't going to be a simple process unfortunately.

Comment: We're really looking for the full shebang on a daily basis, the company I work for is a data warehouse, so that was really the real goal when it came to using Chatter =(

Comment: Are you just trying to get the Chatter feed?

Comment: Chatter feed, group conversations, private messages etcetra

Comment: Would something like this help you? http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/chatterapi/Content/connect_resource_feeds_news.htm

Comment: I believe it would, would this also obtain deleted items?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure. I would assume deleted items would just be removed from the feed.

Comment: just to get this going in the right direction should be fine, there's always room for expansion AFTER the groundwork is laid ;)